# Upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, experiencing extremely bad sound quality

Tags: audio, windows-10

I just upgraded my hp 1000 notebook PC from windows 8.1 to 10 and the sound quality has been extremely poor. 
I am using the very same headphones and surprised to hear such bad sound.

It seems quite nice that everything I had in windows 8.1 is completely saved with my settings, but no idea about this **Sound Quality** thingy.

Will be grateful for any help in this regard. :)

Comment: What's bad sound quality to you?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Bad sound quality means bad sound actually. Well you might wanna say, the bass is missing and you feel like you are listening to an old radio.

Comment: There's distortion, clipping, tinnyness. I really do consider 'bad sound' to be horribly vague.  Do you/did you have any 'sound enhancement' type things  previously? Is there a 'beats' logo anywhere on your PC?

Comment: Perhaps try uninstalling and reinstalling/upgrading your soundcard/chipset drivers? Also, is this a straight upgrade, or did you upgrade/clean install? If the former, I'd recommend a clean install, as it can potentially eliminate random issues.

Comment: did you check if your sound card has a new driver for Windows 10?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with a Dell XPS 12 laptop.  The sound quality was good with Windows 8.1, but after upgrading to Windows 10 I have no bass and it just sounds bad.  There are no sound effects or enhancements options to disable with my driver.  I checked for driver updates and it didn't find anything.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes I did, and I uninstalled and reinstalled the latest drivers from hp official site. No offense, but Microsoft did something really bad with Windows 10. I am making my PC go back to a previous state of Windows 8.1.

Comment: With the accepted answer, you are telling Windows to allow the device to enhance all sound throughput from the device. It's actually a temporary fix. The problem reoccurred for me after a few days/months. I've found a fix that seems to be permanent for me. Uninstall the driver completely and go to http://download.viatech.com/en/support/driversSelect.jsp and select Windows 10 (there's only one driver available named Vinyl). Download that and run the setup.exe to install. That did the trick for me.

Comment: I had this happening on a Dell XPS 15 9560, for me updating to the latest Realtek driver solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your audio driver is Realtek then try the following, it worked for me:

- right click on audio icon from taskbar
- click Playback devices
- select Speakers/HP
- click Properties
- go to Advanced tab
- uncheck "Enable audio enhancements"
- click Apply, click Ok.

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much! My music is back I am feeling extremely delighted! <3

Comment: If option "Enable audio enhancements" it's not present, try @Matt 's answer (= It worked!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, this worked for me though:

- right click on audio icon from taskbar
- click Playback devices
- select Speakers/HP
- click Properties
- go to enhancements tab
- click disable all sound effects
- click Apply, click Ok.

Don't know why it worked, but sound is back to normal and it doesn't sound like a pirated copy of music from someone's flip phone anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem with a Dell XPS 12 laptop which has a Realtek audio system. The sound quality was good with Windows 8.1, but after upgrading to Windows 10 I had no bass and it just sounded bad. There are no sound effects or enhancements options to disable with my driver. I checked for driver updates via Windows and it didn't find anything.  But then I went to the Dell support site and they had an updated Realtek driver package which I downloaded and installed.  It made a huge difference.  The sound quality is now as good as it was before updating to Windows 10.  You might want to check HP's support site to see if they have updated drivers for your system.

Comment: The above solutions given by @itsrajib and Matt worked for me. Give it a try! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded to Windows 10 today, same problem.  Bass response is minimal using NVIDIA High Definition Audio driver and extant playback arrangement, which previously worked fine under Windows 7.

I've tried disabling all Enhancements (Sound > Playback > Properties), I've tried setting the speakers to full range (Sound > Playback > Configure), I've tried toggling the bit depth (Sound > Playback > Properties > Advanced), and I've even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver, all to no avail.  Seems like a Windows 8/10 glitch from everything I've read this afternoon.

Might try living with it briefly, to give Microsoft an opportunity to fix the problem, might revert to Windows 7.  Pretty annoying.

Comment: While very descriptive, this unfortunately does not answer the question.

Comment: You can try reverting to the Microsoft HD Audio class driver to see if this solves the problem. If so, then the issue is the nVidia driver not playing well with Windows 10 audio enhancements

Comment: FWIW, I wound up grabbing (from Dell, in my case) the "Realtek-High-Definition-Audio-Driver_MMRRR_WIN_6.0.1.8622_A14.EXE", which replaced the one  I grabbed from RealTek, and it solved the problem.