# Windows audio sounds muffled when plugging headphones back in

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

I've recently began to encounter an issue where my audio would sound very muffled. Often times, voices are completely drowned out by some other audio. For example, when playing Overwatch, I can barely hear any character's voice, and all the other sounds are muffled.

This can be fixed by fully reinstalling the Realtek audio driver, but it requires two restarts to fully install, which is obviously a minor inconvenience when I just plug my headphones back in.

I even tried fully uninstalling Realtek, and it seemed to work fine for a bit, but then it just becomes muffled again.

It's not the headphones either, I tried on a laptop and it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like https://superuser.com/a/1599410/1482432 Let us know if the same fix worked for you